# Console.ReadLine doesn't wait for input

Tags: c#

I was writing this code and noticed that the `Console.ReadLine()` command doesn't wait for input. Those lines are being executed for sure but for some reason the console just closes on me without being able to type.

The class is set to be console application.

```
   public void Register()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter User Name to Register:");
        String nickname = Console.ReadLine();
        User newUser = new User(nickname);    //todo: check if it doesn't already exist//
        this.userList.Add(newUser);
        persistantLayer.Saver.saveUser(newUser);
    }
```

Comment: And you're 100% sure the whole project is build as Console Application? Do you have a class or variable that is called Console? Please provide an [MCVE]

Comment: "_Those Lines are being excuted for sure_". I am only sure that i can't take your words at face value. ;-) What evidence do you have that those lines are really executed? How did you validate this claim?

Comment: lol i just wrote there a for loop from 1 to 10000 which was printing the indexes and watched them being printed on the console.

Comment: Just try to put this code in Main method and verify that you are right about it.

Comment: just did, runs fine there on main.

Comment: For loop? printing indexes? lol? I am not following you...

Comment: the loop isn't there offcourse. I just wrote it for myself to verify the lines above it was being compiled.

Comment: sorry for confusing you.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/TjUNE

Comment: Well, if you are sure that Register() is called, then either you have created another Console class with static methods mimicking the System.Console class (as rene suggested in his comment). Or your program (or any of the 3rd libraries you might use) redirects the console standard input via `Console.SetIn(...)` or some other means. Anyway, that's just blind-guessing. Over the internet it is not possible to say with confidence what is going on there with your program. I guess you need to debug more thoroughly to figure out what's happening there...

Comment: thanks, I check my program for these issue and the do not exist. I have noticed though that if I replace "Console.ReadLine()" with "Console.ReadKey()" it does wait for my input (but for just one char, and I wish to enter a String offcourse). this is so wierd. Is there any chance that you could review my code if I share it with you?

Comment: ok I have managed to resolve this somehow, thanks